# Difference between browsers

Tags: html, css, browser

I have one question. I want to know how to solve the following example:

I create html page with "div" tag and in browsers looks different...

CSS code:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
}

@font-face{
    font-family:myFont;
    src:url('PTN57F.ttf');
}

body{
    background:#f5f5f5;
}

.content{
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    background:#EEE;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:myFont;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Browsers different:

[image]

Problem is in font weight and padding. Is there any solution on this?

Comment: @j08691 i have try this and is not better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers/systems have different rendering engine, hence the output rendered by them will be different. And no noone serious about webdev is going to complain about it. That's just the way it is - deal with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly set two things via css and it should give you a much closer cross-browser experience:

```
font-weight: 300 //<-- this can be 100, 200, 300...900
line-height: 1.5em // <-- this is em or px and should be roughly 1.5x your font size
```

Comment: then it may be something you need to live with. OSX just renders fonts way nicer than Windows in most instances. Plus it could just be the screen resolution of your computers. Does your OSX have retina display and your PC only have crappy resolution? You might also try `-webkit-text-stroke: .5px` ... it will bold text, but you will need to figure out windows vs osx to load it only sometimes.

Comment: what is with "padding-top"? Is there any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normalize.css file to make browsers display everything as similar as possible.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: I have try this and is not better.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in screen resolution, 1000px in typical display would be **N** santimeters, but in high resolution displays, it would be **N - x**, where x is screen resolution difference, thats why your margin-top: 40px renders differently, try to use margin-top: 5%